# Docker on Windows Desktop - can one have VOLUMEs on logical drives?

Tags: windows, docker, docker-desktop

I am trying to create a few scripts that allow different developers to run Docker containers as conveniently as possible. Several containers need to share some data directories with their host system and thus I am using dockers VOLUME command and docker run's -v option, resp.

The sharing works ok, if I enter the "real" full path (e.g. C:\Users... down to the actual directory), but not when I use a path relative to any "logical" drive.
We are using logical drive letters, since individual developers have set up their development environments differently. We thus typically refer to the root of our project files using a logical D:\ drive, so that our scripts can use "relative" paths (i.e. absolute to that logical drive D:). These drive-letters are created using a SUBST   command (or some equivalent mechanism like via registry-entry or using the VisualSubst tool).

It seems that Docker for Desktop on Windows can't handle such drives at all, at least one can't select them in Settings -> Shared Drives. To be precise: one CAN select them but after clicking "Apply" the tickmark is gone again. ||-(

Is there any way or trick to get around that limitation? It would be very cumbersome if every developer first had to adapt these scripts and edit his/her personal project-root into these scripts. :-(

Comment: I remember running into this issue a year ago or so and was never able to find a solution or even a hacky workaround. If I were facing your issue now, i'd probably just use something like SyncToy (or file sync tool/script of your choice) to sync the virtual drive with a local path on your C:\ and mount that as a volume. I hope someone has a real answer for this as this is a very common use-case.

Comment: @leeman24 Thanks for responding. I don't quite get what you mean by "syncing" here. The "logical" drive D: (note: I changed the description, since "logical" drive seems to be the correct term, not "virtual" drive) points to some arbitrary directory on C: anyway, so I don't see what needs to be synced here. It's always inherently in sync with that directory. Maybe you were just confused by my former unprecise description?

Comment: I was suggesting that you sync the files to a location that docker can use. If you already have the files mounted on your C:\ you may just want to point it there which I know is not ideal. I don't think there is any good workarounds for this.